# same python code not working on mac but working on linux

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code below which works perfectly on linux but it's not working on mac.
I have tried to find why it's not working and if I do not make plot with matplotlib on `onPositionChange` function, the code is working on mac. So I believe the trouble comes from `matplotlib` but I can not figure out why...

I have install the exact same `matplotlib` library in both system : `3.1.2` and I am using `python3`.

Here is my error in the console :

```
2021-05-12 16:52:25.941 Python[60747:697875] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'NSWindow drag regions should only be invalidated on the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff206646af __exceptionPreprocess + 242
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff2039c3c9 objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff2068ca9a -[NSException raise] + 9
        3   AppKit                              0x00007fff22e33460 -[NSWindow(NSWindow_Theme) _postWindowNeedsToResetDragMarginsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 321
        4   AppKit                              0x00007fff22e1e121 -[NSWindow _initContent:styleMask:backing:defer:contentView:] + 1375
        5   AppKit                              0x00007fff22e1dbbb -[NSWindow initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:] + 42
        6   _macosx.cpython-39-darwin.so        0x0000000125d10755 -[Window initWithContentRect:styleMask:backing:defer:withManager:] + 69
        7   _macosx.cpython-39-darwin.so        0x0000000125d13abf FigureManager_init + 287
        8   Python                              0x000000010ac94d56 wrap_init + 12
        9   Python                              0x000000010ac2fc93 wrapperdescr_call + 411
        10  Python                              0x000000010ac256da _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 129
        11  Python                              0x000000010ad1dcbd call_function + 270
        12  Python                              0x000000010ad1b526 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45324
        13  Python                              0x000000010ac26240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
        14  Python                              0x000000010ac25907 _PyObject_FastCallDictTstate + 87
        15  Python                              0x000000010ac94aea slot_tp_init + 192
        16  Python                              0x000000010ac9e2cc type_call + 272
        17  Python                              0x000000010ac256da _PyObject_MakeTpCall + 129
        18  Python                              0x000000010ad1dcbd call_function + 270
        19  Python                              0x000000010ad1b526 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45324
        20  Python                              0x000000010ac26240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
        21  Python                              0x000000010ac28e7a method_vectorcall + 160
        22  Python                              0x000000010ad1dc53 call_function + 164
        23  Python                              0x000000010ad1b526 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45324
        24  Python                              0x000000010ad0f2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
        25  Python                              0x000000010ac262f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
        26  Python                              0x000000010ac28e7a method_vectorcall + 160
        27  Python                              0x000000010ac25ee1 PyVectorcall_Call + 164
        28  Python                              0x000000010ad1b75e _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45892
        29  Python                              0x000000010ad0f2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
        30  Python                              0x000000010ac262f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
        31  Python                              0x000000010ad1dc53 call_function + 164
        32  Python                              0x000000010ad1b562 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45384
        33  Python                              0x000000010ac26240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
        34  Python                              0x000000010ad1dc53 call_function + 164
        35  Python                              0x000000010ad1b562 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45384
        36  Python                              0x000000010ad0f2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
        37  Python                              0x000000010ac262f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
        38  Python                              0x000000010ad1dc53 call_function + 164
        39  Python                              0x000000010ad1b562 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45384
        40  Python                              0x000000010ad0f2d6 _PyEval_EvalCode + 403
        41  Python                              0x000000010ac262f8 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 376
        42  Python                              0x000000010ad1dc53 call_function + 164
        43  Python                              0x000000010ad1b612 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45560
        44  Python                              0x000000010ac26240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
        45  Python                              0x000000010ad1dc53 call_function + 164
        46  Python                              0x000000010ad1b526 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 45324
        47  Python                              0x000000010ac26240 _PyFunction_Vectorcall + 192
        48  Python                              0x000000010ac28f47 method_vectorcall + 365
        49  _ctypes.cpython-39-darwin.so        0x000000010b23eb28 _CallPythonObject + 568
        50  _ctypes.cpython-39-darwin.so        0x000000010b23e8ea closure_fcn + 46
        51  libffi.dylib                        0x00007fff2db304bb ffi_closure_unix64_inner + 481
        52  libffi.dylib                        0x00007fff2db30a7c ffi_closure_unix64 + 72
        53  Phidget22                           0x0000000126155b2f PhidgetChannel_bridgeInput + 907
        54  Phidget22                           0x000000012619b120 PhidgetDispatcher + 1305
        55  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff204f2950 _pthread_start + 224
        56  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00007fff204ee47b thread_start + 15
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
Abort trap: 6
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from Phidget22.Phidget import *
from Phidget22.Devices.Encoder import *
import time
import json
import numpy as np
from scipy import zeros, signal, random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


from scipy import signal
from numpy import linalg as LA

array = []
bigArray = []
bigArrayControl = []
filterData = []
i = 0

ii = 0
dataInterval = 20
index = 0


def filter_sbs(data):
    data = random.random(2000)

    b = signal.firwin(50, 0.05)
    z = signal.lfilter_zi(b, 1)
    result = zeros(data.size)
    result[i], z = signal.lfilter(b, 1, data, axis=0, zi=z)
    return result

def butter(data):
    fs = 1000 / dataInterval  # Sampling frequency
    L = len(data)
    print(L)
    # # Generate the time vector properly
    t = np.arange(L) / fs

    fc = 20  # Cut-off frequency of the filter
    w = fc / (fs / 2) # Normalize the frequency
    b, a = signal.butter(4, w, 'low')
    outputX = signal.filtfilt(b, a, data,axis=0)
    
    return outputX

def filterRealTime(data):
    global zi, ii
    fs = 1000 / dataInterval  # Sampling frequency
    L = len(data)
    t = np.arange(L) / fs

    fc = 20  # Cut-off frequency of the filter
    w = fc / (fs / 2) # Normalize the frequency
    b, a = signal.butter(4, w, 'low')
    if (ii == 0):
        ii = 1  
        zi = signal.lfiltic(b,a,[0])
    y, zi = signal.lfilter(b,a, data, axis=0, zi=zi)
    #print(zi)
    return y


def onPositionChange(self, positionChange, timeChange, indexTriggered):
    global i 
    global array, bigArray, filterData
    array.append(positionChange)
    bigArray.append(positionChange)
    send_msg = {
        'data': array,
    }
    if (len(array) == 50 and len(bigArray) <= 500):
        global index, filterData, bigArrayControl
        result = filterRealTime(array)
        bigArrayControl.extend(array)
        array = []
        index = index + 1
        filterData.extend(result)

        

    if (len(bigArray) == 50):
        npBigArray = np.array(bigArray)
        data = random.random(50)
        result = butter(npBigArray)
        print(filterData)
        plt.plot(filterData, 'b-', label='filter')
        plt.show()


def main():
    encoder0 = Encoder()

    encoder0.setOnPositionChangeHandler(onPositionChange)

    encoder0.openWaitForAttachment(5000)
    encoder0.setDataInterval(dataInterval)


    try:
        input("Press Enter to Stop\n")
    except (Exception, KeyboardInterrupt):
        pass

    encoder0.close()

main()
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what you mean by "it's not working on mac". Do you get an error message? Does it just not display a plot? Does it create a plot, but the plot is not what you were expecting?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to put the error, I have uptated my post, thank you

Comment: Is that the entire error message?

Comment: it's a bit longer... I have updated the post @AMC

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing the import of Matplotlib to this?

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

or

```
import matplotlib  
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working, I got an error. "ImportError: Failed to import any qt binding"

Comment: What about the `TkAgg` backend? Any error messages?

Comment: Here is what I got : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_tkinter'